# Missing articles in "like teacher or nurse"

Tags: grammar, articles

I have a paragraph in power point slides:

> Women only allowed certain jobs, like teacher or nurse

I don't see articles in *"like teacher or nurse,"* as I expect countable words such as teacher or nurse should have articles or in plural forms.

Is this allowed in general for presentation purposes, or is this a simple mistake?

Comment: It's [headlinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headlinese), which often omits simple verbs and prepositions.

Comment: You could consider "teacher" or "nurse" as job categories and as such no article would be used. Persons working in these professions don't have such a title, but instead like "registered nurse" or "teacher's aide".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Amazing! I was wondering  why some news articles do that all the time and just get irritated reading such instances for years. It ought to be posted as an answer. Besides I notice too many of your comments to be good answers. Why not post them as an answer?

Comment: @Ébe Isaac: We get lots of questions like this both here and on ELU. Both sites have the tag **headlinese** here expanded upon as *'Headlinese' is the very elliptical syntax employed in headlines, captions, titles, signs and labels in order to save space and permit larger characters in display.* And ELL has [62 questions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headlinese) with that tag, so most likely at least one of them would be suitable for referencing in a "duplicate" closevote (I just don't know which one! :)

Comment: Even if it weren't a terse caption, you wouldn't need an article there.  *There are many career paths open to students, among them astronaut, doctor, nurse, and teacher.*   These nouns refer to the category prototype, not to an instance of the type.